# Seeing Through The Earth

Tags: earth-like, hollow-earth

What would happen if the earth was made up of some transparent, see-through material, and it was hollow? Nothing else is different. Would we able to see the other side of the earth, or would it be too far away? How would sunlight affect the Earth? Would it be brighter?

Comment: This seems more like a pure physics question, and a rather broad one at that. Maybe try asking just the first part on [physics.SE].

Comment: It depends on how hollow , if it is too hollow , it make very well collapse on its self , also , nothing it perfectly clear , so the other side may look fairly dim and blurry, and almost certainly upside down , due to the curvature of the world.

Comment: Not to mention that it would have no magnetosphere and be to thin to support life

Comment: Is there a specific result you're trying to achieve with this? That might be a better way to present a worldbuilding question.

Comment: I'm not at all sure I agree with the "too broad" close votes. The question gives three fairly specific questions, seemingly all relating to optics, which should be fairly answerable. Note to **user314999**, we generally prefer questions that show evidence of own research (even if that is just something like stating "I read the Wikipedia article on light propagation but couldn't figure out what the effects of a transparent planet would be because X and Y").

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as mentioned in the comments this could be better answered at physics. It's mainly a problem with optics, rayleigh-scattering ect.

Comment: Its not really a physics question as described in the physics help centre because it is very hypothetical.

Comment: This would be a good candidate for the What-If SE, if it ever gets made.

Comment: wouldn’t the temperature inside rise like crazy?

Answer (score 4):

The answers to this are pretty much clear cut physics based.

- Would we be able to see the other side?  Of course.  Your description calls for a thin transparent material, and empty space.  Neither of those block light, so you could see through.  Now you wouldn't be able to see much detail.  The Earth is 12,742 km in diameter.  That's about a 20th of the way to the moon, so think about what you can see on the moon.  You can see just about 20x that well, no more.
- The sunlight would be generally unaffected, other than the obvious issue that you no longer have nighttime because the sunlight can go through the earth.  A thin material is unlikely to have any lensing effects, though if you chose your transparent material to have an enormous index of refraction, it could do something.